# Nginx with zookeeper and kafka

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

How to make kafka and zookeeper work with nginx? I have tried setting up nginx before but there is a severe lack of results in finding how to configure for kafka and zookeeper in nginx.

I have tried using this following configuration for kafka and zookeeper. However, I am unsure if this allows the connection to kafka and zookeeper. As kafka and zookeeper are meant to be for backend, thus it is set to 443. Please advice if I am heading in the correct direction.

```
Upstream website {
      10.0.5.15:8755;
}
Upstream zoo {
      10.0.5.20:2181;
}
Upstream kafka {
      10.0.5.20:9092;
}


server {
    listen 80;
    server_name same.sg;
    location / {
        proxy_hide_header       Server;
        proxy_hide_header       X-Powered-By;
        proxy_hide_header       X-AspNet-Version;
        proxy_hide_header       Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://website;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name same.sg;
    ssl_certificate /cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /server.key;

    location /kafka {
       internal;
       proxy_pass https://kafka;
    }

    location /zoo {
       internal;
       proxy_pass https://zoo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Lack of results? [This has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nginx+apache-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper and Kafka use TCP, not HTTP/S, therefore will not work behind such a Proxy.

Nginx has a `stream` directive for TCP connections, however Kafka clients must connect directly to individual brokers after bootstrapping, so introducing a load balancer or proxy becomes a single point of failure for the bootstrap protocol.

External Kafka clients never need to connect to Zookeeper, plus latest Kafka versions are removing Zookeeper altogether